# Using sudo su for commands?

Tags: command-line

I was working on developing my command line skills last night and ran into an issue where when I used sudo, I got an error message that said 'permission denied'. However when I used 'sudo su' and became root the command worked.

Why didn't sudo work in the first instance?

It was:

```
$ sudo cat > /var/www/info. php
<?php
phpinfo( ) ;
? >
^D
```

From the Linux Bible 2010 edition in the section on setting up a LAMP server.

Comment: If you don't give an example it's kind of hard to resolve the problem.

Comment: Consider `sudo -s` over `sudo su`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The <, > and >> are used for input / output redirection for commands - which is a feature provided by the shell (e.g., bash). So if you type a command like `sudo cat > /var/www/info.php` then the shell that receives this as input tries to open the file `/var/www/info.php` and provides that file as the standard output to the `sudo` command. The `sudo` command is not even aware whether its output is going to a console or redirected to a file, because this is taken care of by the shell that invokes it.

If the shell you typed your command into is your login shell or another shell running in a terminal with your user id, then it has same privileges as your user id - not those of root.

So in your case, whereas the cat command is executed as root, the copying of its output to `/var/www/info.php` is attempted by the shell running as a normal user, which, as expected, fails.

A workaround for such situations is to use the `tee` command :

```
sudo tee /var/www/info.php
```

That will have the intended effect of putting all the text entered at the console upto ^D into the file specified as parameter.

One perhaps undersirable side-effect is that `tee` will also echo the output to the stdout, so after you type each line and press enter `tee` will output a copy of it back. To avoid this you can use the following variant.

```
sudo tee /var/www/info.php > /dev/null
```

Details about `tee` can be had via `info tee` at a terminal.

Answer (score 2):

sudo does not work for commands that need permissions to write a file, such as:

`sudo echo "vm.swappines = 100" >> /etc/sysctl.conf`

It explains in the sudo man-page.

Comment: Mentioning that you can "sudo -i" or "sudo -s" to get a root prompt would make this answer even better!

Comment: There is no pipe in the example command; there is a redirection. Also, "sometimes does not work" seems to convey flaky behavior by `sudo`. As noted in koushik's answer, the behavior is quite predictable, consistent, and "correct" for the unix permission model.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the "> foo.txt" part is interpreted and executed by your command interpreter (shell) *long* before the sudo command is being run.  The sudo command has no idea that you want to redirect its output to a file.

Your command interpreter does not have root authority (but the sudo command will eventually later) so it cannot redirect the output to foo.txt.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to solve this is to start a subshell with sudo and execute that command in that subshell:

```
$ sudo bash -c "cat > /var/www/info.php"
<?php
phpinfo( ) ;
? >
^D
```

here, the command that "has sudo" is bash, and anything executed in it has root permissions.

$2c,
*-pike